# marvin image color difference plugin error

Tags: java, marvin-framework

I am getting a null pointer exception whenever i am trying to process two images for color difference. The code is

```
MarvinImageIO.saveImage(currentFrame, "check1.jpg");
                MarvinImageIO.saveImage(template, "check2.jpg");

                currentFrame=MarvinImageIO.loadImage("check1.jpg");
                template=MarvinImageIO.loadImage("check2.jpg");
 //                 System.out.println(currentFrame.getWidth()+"        "+currentFrame.getHeight()+"      "+template.getWidth()+"   "+template.getHeight());

                scale(currentFrame, template, template.getWidth(),    template.getHeight());

                MarvinImagePlugin diff =       MarvinPluginLoader.loadImagePlugin("org.marvinproject.image.difference.differenc     eColor.jar");
                MarvinAttributes attr = new MarvinAttributes();
                attr.set("total", 0);


                System.out.println(attr.get("total"));
                diff.process(currentFrame, template,attr);
```

The error is on the diff.process statement. The images are not null and so is the attr.

Error statement is

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.marvinproject.image.difference.differenceColor.DifferenceColor.process(DifferenceColor.java:67)
at marvin.plugin.MarvinAbstractImagePlugin.process(MarvinAbstractImagePlugin.java:65)
at censor_player.player$MyThread.run(player.java:142)
```

Comment: I'm actually facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: same issue. simple search doesn't find anything helpful. Change to `MarvinPluginCollection.findSubimage` can run without NPE. But result is always null (means not found), add similarity no help. While findSubimage works good with some other image, maybe some issue with the image or format?